# Why Does "Port 9100" Printing Multi-Page PDF Cause HP 4515 to Pause Between Pages?

Tags: pdf, printing

I create thousands of PDF files per day and print them on a set of HP-4515 printers using a Ruby on Rails app with Prawn. After a couple of years of production printing, I noticed yet another HP anomaly today: a simple 47kB 10-page file of tables causes the HP printer to pause for several seconds between pages. (the tables do not span pages).

I have a custom print spooler that ensures certain bundles of documents are printed coherently from submissions in a call center, and this spooler logs how many bytes are written into the printer's port 9100 socket.  Oddly, this 47kB file logs 6,442kB of bytes sent (137 times!), and it takes 71 seconds.  Most socket writes of 50kB files take only a few milliseconds, unless the printer gets backed up (and I have several techniques of throttling my file writes to avoid bogging the printers down, which improves throughput.  This throttling only delays between files, not within them).

The multiple pages are created using Prawn's @pdf.start_new_page.  Viewing the PDF in OSX's Skim or Preview shows nothing unexpected.

None of my other ~100 PDF file types cause this strange printer-pause, although almost all of the other file types are single page.

All other @socket.write(str) calls actually send the number of bytes in the file.

The files have proprietary court case information, so I can't just attach a sample.  If anyone has a suggestion, perhaps I could create a similar file using nonsense data....

BTW - I have found HP's support useless, despite the amount we pay for it.

Comment: Long pauses between pages is almost always font issues for me.  Is your driver PCL5?  Sometimes just using the PCL5 driver is enough to fix it.  Otherwise change the pdf to use the same fonts as the other ones that don't take forever.

Comment: Nothing really helpful to add as this is a rather obscure topic, but have you isolated the problem to the printer: i.e. sent the document directly to the printer without using a print server/special spooler/other software in the middle. If the problem persists it's probably a driver bug (and you can try updating or roll-backing), if not is something in your setup (and you can do something proactive to fix it.)

Answer (score 0):

I seriously doubt that your HP printer is able to consume PDF files directly.

I suspect your so called "custom spooler" silently converts PDF files to PCL or PostScript (just as CUPS would do) in order to serve the print device a data format that is digestible to it.

And it likely is this converted data (PCL, PostScript, whatever) which produces 6.442 kB of Bytes sent to the printer.

In order to verify or debug this situation, you should use some of the available techniques which capture the actual data sent to the printer...